# How to deal with special characters in URLs inside XML

Tags: php, javascript, xml, url, special-characters

I have an XML element that has a url as one of it's children, for example:
http://maps.google.com/FortWorth&Texas,more+url;data

When parsing this, I'm having two issues:
1.) The (**&**) symbol breaks the entire parse unless replaced with **&amp** (which breaks the url)
2.) The comma (**,**) tries to send my parser on to the next child, resulting in an incomplete url.

What can I do to remedy this?
I'm using Javascript and PHP.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Replacing `&` with `&amp;` shouldn't break the url. Did you left out the ;?

Better solution is you should wrap that in a CDATA tag:

`<![CDATA[ http://maps.google.com/FortWorth&Texas,more+url;data ]]>`

Which tells the XML parser to treat it as text and not parse the &.

Comment: This is the best solution, actually. +1!

Comment: This is tragic. XML is supposed to be structured data consisting of valid elements and properties. CDATA allow a programmer to get lazy. It basically tells the XML parser, don't bother parsing this, this may not be valid, just ignore it.

Comment: +1 Great solution, didn't find better on the web. @Dmitri: in my scenario where ordinary user enter urls to XML file and I only read from it then it's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

There are certain characters which are not valid in XML - you need to "escape" these in the xml document.

These characters and their "escaped" versions are:

```
>  &gt;
<  &lt;
&  &amp;
'   &apos;
"   &quot;
```

Comment: this is correct, but you should provide examples of how to encode them, e.g. with htmlentities() and html_entity_decode() when retrieving them.

Comment: @El Yobo - sorry, I'm not a PHP programmer :)